# Using add columns in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I was hoping to not have to go through the manual process creating more columns and was trying to use the following SQL script (inside phpMyAdmin). It says there is a syntax error but I have not found 1 working example of using add columns. I see lots of examples of "add column" but not multiple. Even when looking at the manual, I don't see where my syntax error is. thoughts?

```
ALTER TABLE assessment_info ADD COLUMNS
`condition` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`rec_cuts` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`rec_burns` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`rec_infection` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`rec_dermatitis` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`rec_puncture` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`rec_sprain` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`rec_impact` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`non_rec_cuts` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`non_rec_burns` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`non_rec_infection` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`non_rec_dermatitis` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`non_rec_puncture` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`non_rec_sprain` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`non_rec_impact` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`cost_of_productivity` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`leakage` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`usage_rate` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`cost_per_pair` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
`competitor` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`
```

Comment: You'll need a comma `,` after each of the new column definitions (except the last one) and an `ADD` keyword.

Comment: You have no `,` after ANY of those new fields.

Comment: MySQL is usually very, very specific about the location of a syntax error. Pay attention to these messages and follow their advice.

Comment: Example: `ALTER TABLE assessment_info ADD condition varchar(500) AFTER non_rec_injuries_timeframe, ADD rec_cuts varchar(500) AFTER....`

Comment: adding a coma caused an immediate "unrecognized alter operation" error so thoughts my I had left that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no `ADD COLUMNS` option to `ALTER TABLE` (see the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)).

You seem to intend:

```
ALTER TABLE assessment_info
    ADD COLUMN `condition` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`,
    ADD COLUMN `rec_cuts` varchar(500) AFTER `non_rec_injuries_timeframe`,
    . . .
```

Comment: YES! That worked. the page you reference was what I was originally talking about how no one has shown examples of "add columns". thank you